# Microsoft Outlook Rule - Any way to have it automatically delete items that are over 1 week old?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter, autoarchive

Basically I have a rule setup to filter specific incoming emails into a folder and mark them read. I do this because I get about a couple hundred per day and I only keep them around if I need to reference something.

If an item is over a week old, there is no need to EVER reference it (it's useless). So, to keep the folder clean I was hoping there is a way to automatically have it move any items to the trash if they are over 1 week old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the **AutoArchive** settings for that folder that will delete old items if these items are 1 week old.